# PCH warning: header stop cannot be in a macro or #if block

Tags: c++, macros

I came across this PCH issue in VS c++. i have done some searches before asking here. it seems that adding #pragma once would solve the problem. However, i wonder if there is another way.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003603/pch-warning-header-stop-cannot-be-in-a-macro-or-if-block-visual-c-2010-exp) resource link

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a visual studio 2010 bug. It'll go away when you add a .cpp file and include the singleton header in it.