# IntelliSense PCH Warning not going away

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, pch

I have a ATL C++ project and I don't have any includes in one of my C++ source files.

When I try to compile, I am receiving a PCH warning:

> Error (active) E2940   PCH warning: an unknown error occurred.  An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated.

But the project compiles fine alongside with this warning.

I tried adding `#pragma once` and `include "stdafx.h"` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215981/how-do-i-stop-an-intellisense-pch-warning) post, but any of them did not resolve this issue.

What else can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Usually this happens when you don't follow implicit Microsoft's conventions for organizing your project. You don't put external includes such as <vector> to your stdafx.h, for instance.

Comment: @MinorThreat unloading solution and reloading worked for mine!

Comment: I've had this problem when my stdafx.h was almost empty&abandoned and standard libraries were included in traditional C++ way.

Comment: @MinorThreat Thanks for help! As you say mine also is almost empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27374397/6536104) answer, closing and re-opening the solution worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi GTAVLover, glad to hear that your issue is solved and please mark your reply as answer when you have free time :) , it will help other community members to easier search this information.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I just had an error in the program  with `std` so I started using `namespace std` and it worked. I also added 
    `#pragma once`